# wp_tag_cloud display results on simple page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need your advice! I have WP site. Post by categories is displayed not via category.php but within a simple page template. For this reason, I have a specific route to post not **my.site.com/cat/news-en/post-name** but **my.site.com/mediacenter/news/post-name**. On page with all posts I wanna display tag cloud. When I use `<?php wp_tag_cloud(); ?>` the cloud is displayed as expected. But on click result is displayed on archive.php page. How can I change it to be displyed om my current simple.php page **my.site.com/mediacenter/news/results**?